# Trying to create new tuple column on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I'm trying to create a new column, a tuple based on two existing columns:

```
dff['net_sys']= dff[['network', 'syscode']].apply(lambda x: (x['network'], x['syscode']),axis=1)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
dff['net_sys']= dff[['network', 'syscode']].apply(tuple,axis=1)
```

Or

```
dff['net_sys']=list(zip(dff['network'],dff['syscode']))
```